# How to play Elder Scrolls Arena (DOS) with keyboard only?

Tags: dosbox, the-elder-scrolls-arena

I downloaded this game, "Elders Scrolls: Arena Deluxe Edition" and started it on DOSBox to emulate and play it. Although it's working fine, the problem is that I can attack with the mouse but wanted to know if there's a way to attack with the keyboard, as I am finding some difficulties using my mouse. In this situation, I am not able to escape from the dungeon as I am defeated easily. I am running DOSBox in Windows 7 32-bit.

Is there any way to play this game with the keyboard only? Or configure DOSBox in such a way that I can specify to use some keys as right click and left click instead of using a mouse? Or are there other software that can do it?

Sorry if everyone misunderstood it. I want to remap mouse keys to be used by pressing some key on the keyboard like if I press <kbd>J</kbd> it should work just like pressing the left mouse button. And to swipe mouse from left to right and vice versa like doing it from a mouse. Just like Bluestack has done with itself.

Comment: http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#KeyMapper shows how to remap keys in DOSBox.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I know how to remap keys in Dosbox but how can I remap mouse clicks to keyboard buttons? That's my actual question.

Comment: Ah.  Didn't realize there wasn't an option to map a button to the mouse click, and I don't have DOSBox here to test with.

Comment: Just for some info I used GlovePIE and am able to use mouse buttons precisely but what about dragging the mouse left or right (to be able to attack in the game) as I cannot find the right input for this.

Answer (score 3):

The game manual states specifically that a mouse is required to play the game properly. Since the fighting system is swiping your mouse across the screen, you cannot play pure keyboard.

That said, I think you might just about manage what you want to achieve if you are willing to play using only a bow and spells. But that strategy will already give you a hard time in the starting dungeon, let alone the rest of the game.

So unfortunately, no mouse is too much of a handicap to play this game.